# How does the "conspiracy theory" work in China and for what purpose?

Tags: china

I am Chinese and have been surrounded by the "conspiracy theory" that the U.S. has been intending to destroy China for a long time.

Proponents of this theory

- cite the [Plaza Accord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaza_Accord) as evidence  that America stopped Japan's progress to prevent her from occupying America's global market, and conclude that China is next.
- claim  that  the Soviet Union in the early stage trusted America but was cheated, *[SOHU.com](https://www.sohu.com/a/579569649_121165100)*
- videos claim that  Putin once trusted America and even wanted to join NATO.   *[SOHU.com](https://www.sohu.com/a/579569649_121165100)*

Is there any **evidence** of a US policy to destroy China?  Is there evidence to contradict these claims?  Is this a continuation of the Cold War?

I'm not trying to engage the conspiracy theorists; I'm trying to educate myself and figure out what is propaganda and what is legitimate history.

I don't know if what I learned was a part of propaganda like those in the book 1984 to distract our attention from issues inside China. Things like home prices dropping, strict Covid-19 control and people's silently complaining, the succession problem made by Xi, Taiwan problem etc.

I want to know more about the cold war because it seems that the war is still going on, but between China and probably "her imaginary enemy" America.

Are there some strategic relations between Russia, Japan and China? What rules have America played with the three Asian countries? How does the conspiracy theory work in China (or maybe also other countries like Russia and etc) for what purpose?

Comment: [reference requests](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4132/requests-for-references) are generally discouraged here, except for canonical references.  They are a type of [shopping question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) that tends to generate lots of opinion and few [Authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401)

Comment: Attempted a first cut revision. Let me know if this helps

Comment: @MCW Thanks! Where you marked *citation needed* can be these two: corn campaign and https://www.sohu.com/a/579569649_121165100

Comment: @MCW I have read a book by Fairbank and know that Americans helped China a lot.

Comment: Given all the effort the USA has put into helping China along over the last 80 years, this is kind of a ridiculous claim.  Its also in [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) territory, as it uses terms so fuzzy that there's no way to prove any assertion about it correct or incorrect.

Comment: @T.E.D more like last 47 years, no? I mean they actually had a war going on 70 years ago.

Comment: @JLL that sohu video you linked to is about Russia post-1990, not about the Soviet Union. Which is important because your claim seems to be about the Soviet Union?

Comment: @Jan for this statement: Putin once trusted America and even wanted to join NATO. It seems to me that Russia is the successor of the Soviet Union. One thing.

Comment: @JLL I see. I forgot to click "read more".

Comment: @Jan - ... in which the [USA after 1941 was actively helping China fight against Japan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_Sino-Japanese_War#Entrance_of_the_Western_Allies), yes. I've personally talked to a pilot who flew supplies for China [over the hump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hump) (the Himalayas) when Japan had them otherwise cut off. That war. FDR went so far as to talk them up as a full Ally equal to Russia and the UK, which is the *entire reason* why China today has a UN Security Council seat.

Comment: @JLL - updated - but please feel free to edit the question to your preferences.

Comment: @T.E.D that was quite a different China.

Comment: @Jan - Well, this is the *history* site. If you want to talk about modern China's modern international relationships, you want a different website.

Comment: @MCW Actually, I don't know what I don't know, and initially I was just asking for some related books to read(to know what I don't know).

Comment: @T.E.D "very different" as in "not communist". The PRC is actually already more than 70 years old. I don't think you want to argue that the US and PRC have always been helping each other.

Comment: @JLL you either need a different source for "the Soviet Union in the early stage trusted America" or clarify what you mean by "in the early stage". It sounds as if you are referring to the 1920s, but your source is entirely about post-WWII. Do you maybe mean the early years after WWII (late 1940s) or the early years after the end of the Cold War (1989 to 1991 or so)?

Comment: I suspect a big part of the answer is that people in general don't understand the distinction between national policy/strategy and behavior.  National actions are influenced by multiple national policies and multiple external events; they don't purely express any policy.

Comment: Revised question is no longer history - recommend migration to politics or another forum.

Comment: Honestly, I think this would get better answers on Politics. They (by necessity) are a lot better than we are with ill-defined terms and questions about motivations.

Answer (score 4):

Most conspiracy narratives -- I hesitate to use the word 'theory' because they are not scientific -- try to explain observed events in the world with some sinister conspiracy, often assigning evil, hidden motives by shadowy power groups. In this case that is completely unnecessary.

- From their public statements, the US wants to create an international order which is compatible with the US economic and social system, and which gives them an influential position in world politics.
- From their public statements, the China wants to create an international order which is compatible with the Chinese economic and social system, and which gives them an influential position in world politics.
- From their public statements, both China and the United States understand that the other is a rival in the shaping of the international order.

No need to 'theorize' about 'conspiracies' ...

This does not mean China and the United States **have** to try and destroy each other. A century ago, the US and the UK were geopolitical rivals, but they came to an accomodation when the UK realized that it could no longer defeat the US, and that their political visions were not necessarily incompatible.

But today China and the US clearly **are** rivals. The US is the status quo power while China is the [revisionist power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_transition_theory). China still smarts from the [unequal treaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unequal_treaty), inflicted in part by the US, and the [incomplete conclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_Civil_War#Aftermath_and_unsolved_issues_(1949%E2%80%93present)) of their civil war, at least as they see it -- again inflicted in part by the US. In their wish to overcome this, China tries to expand their power base, at the expense of US power left from the Cold War alliances.

But the rivalry between the US and China is quite different from the Cold War. The economic interdependency of the West and China is much greater than the trade between the West and the Communist bloc used to be.

As to the history of the Soviet Union and the United States, consider the Allied [intervention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allied_intervention_in_the_Russian_Civil_War) in Russia. Relations were much better while Stalin was fighting Hitler, of course.

After the end of the Cold War, Russian political and military power collapsed. During that time, there was some structured cooperation between Russia and NATO, and *theoretical* talk of a Russian NATO membership. But with their resurgence under President Putin, Russia decided to forcibly secure their influence in many of the ex-Soviet nations, and relations between Russia and the West deteriorated. We simply cannot know how things would have played out if Russia *had* become the second-most-powerful member of NATO. Would that have created an even more messy power struggle a decade later, with NATO paralyzed from within, or would it have reassured Russia so that they could direct their ambitions is more peaceful ways?

Comment: Probably should be added that rulers of unfree societies tend to love foriegner-based conspiracy theories, because they inherently devalue the idea of local political action, and absolve the rulers themselves from any responsibility for events.

Comment: @T.E.D. It needs ACK  that this is way too complicated: you don't need conspiracy, or theory, unfree societies and the whole lot of conditions explicated. "It's Pooten's fault", "My administration made the sun shine". (IMO most laughable version recently: 'SARS2 came to Wuhan in frozen meat packs from abroad') This is a most basic [attribution error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribution_(psychology)): any success is your glorious leadership, any misfortune is external factors. This tendency holds up for any society/system, at best stratified by amount of misfortunes in a given society.

Comment: @LаngLаngС - I think its underappreciated how persecution-based conspiracy theories have been a tool used to neuter political activity in unfree societies, by reinforcing the idea that the people are powerless. Arab Democracy activist [Iyad el-Baghdadi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iyad_el-Baghdadi) has talked and written about this. IIRC, there's a bit in [The Middle East Crisis Factory](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/54429617-the-middle-east-crisis-factory) about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly evidence that the US is somewhat wary of China. I think one can safely assume that the US is not at all interested in China conquering Taiwan and also not a big fan of Chinese actions in the South China Sea. On the other hand the US has, in the past, brought lots and lots of business to China, so the waryness is either quite new or not so bad that it would influence economic decisions much.

By contrast, during the Cold War, Eastern European countries could not even (officially) [import computers from the west](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335742157_From_CoCom_to_Dot-Com_Technological_Determinisms_in_Computing_Blockades_1949_to_1994), so no, we are not at Cold War levels of rivalry yet. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_War) lists a few more commonly-cited features of the Cold War, such as proxy conflicts, a nuclear arms race, and significant military deployments abroad (sometimes [face to face with each other](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlin_Crisis_of_1961)). I don't see any of these either.

Anything about secret plans is of course unknowable (the plans would not be secret otherwise), so I won't comment on that.

I also did not see anything in your source about the Soviet Union (rather than Russia) trusting the US, but I also think that argument is not very relevant to the topic of this question. Foreign powers are per se not very trustworthy.

The bit about Russia asking to join NATO could use more elaboration (though possibly in a separate question). Anyway it is easy to spot at least three grave problems with such an idea, two of which are independent from US interests: 1. Russia wanting to join NATO could easily be interpreted as Russia wanting to influence NATO. From the more recent example of Hungary in the EU, it is easy to see how such influence might not be constructive. 2. NATO by that point had several member states that had experienced what it meant to be in a military alliance with the Soviet Union: [giving up any political leeway](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prague_Spring) and getting nothing in return. 3. Russia at that time was involved in [several](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abkhazia) [armed](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Ossetia) [conflicts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transnistria).